# Integer polynomials with $P(n)P(n+1)\in P(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Find all polynomials $P\in\mathbb Z[x]$ such that for any positive integer $n$, the equation $P(x)=P(n)P(n+1)$ has an integer root.

I think that the only solutions are $P(x)=0$, $P(x)=1$, $P(x)=ax+b$, $P(x)=x^2+ax+b$, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to make much sense

Comment: I agree, also why do you think those are the ones?

Comment: Many authors denote the image by $P(S):=\{P(x):x\in S\}$. We are looking for polynomials with $P(n)P(n+1)$ always in the image of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: $P(x)=ax+b$ doesn't work when $a=0$ and $b=2$, or when $a=3$ and $b=2$.

Comment: I think you can show that, if $P$ is nonconstant, then $P$ is monic and satisfies $$P(X)\,P(X+1)=P\left(X^2+aX+b\right)$$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Could you show me how @Batominovski ?